# How to execute nodejs file in shell script file

Tags: node.js, sh

My first file is run.sh
another file is script.js

run.sh

```
mongo --username --password --authenticationDatabase --host --port script.js
```

script.js

```
require('../config/config');
console.log("came here");
```

But this is not working. i got error

> uncaught exception: ReferenceError: require is not defined :
> @import.js:1:1

Comment: Why are you using mongo for execute nodejs file?

Comment: it might sound unreal but mongo does take a JavaScript file and execute it. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#mongo-shell-javascript-file

Answer (score 1):

There is no module loader in the mongo shell environment.

Config.js sounds like a simple file that contains a mapping of configurations, if that's the case, you can try `load()`

```
// script.js
load("../../config.js")
```

If your `config.js` requires other modules, it's a different story and I wish you good luck...

Answer (score 0):

The `mongo` command starts a MongoDB database. To execute your script, you need to run the command

```
node script.js
```

instead.

If you want to run both, the database and your script, you could start the database in the background first before running `node script.js` by adding a `&` after the database call.